# No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android

On the Resource Chooser I noticed there are some system resources of different Icons. 

[image: http://puu.sh/h3ySG/7d77efbcd1.png]

I wanted to use some in my project. I placed some Icons on buttons, and it showed out as expected:
[image]

But when I tried to run the app, It didn't let because although it showed the resource correctly on the buttons, in the xml file it wrote

> error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawableLeft' with value '@drawable/
>    abc_ic_menu_info_details').

So can I or can I not use these resources?

Comment: try @android:drawable/abc_ic_menu_info_details

Comment: @Prakhar Failed to convert android:drawable/abc_ic_menu_info_details into a drawable, it also doesnt show up on the button anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@android:drawable/abc_ic_menu_info_details`

instead of `@drawable/abc_ic_menu_info_details`

To use system resource your need to start with `@android:`